# Can only use a few sites

Tags: networking

I’ve tried Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora. On all 3 distributions I can connect to Facebook, YouTube and Google, but not any other site. `ping google.com` succeeds, but `ping 8.8.8.8` gives me `Network is unreachable`.

I’ve tried adding DNS in Network Manager and may other solutions, but most of them are blocked by not having `net-tools` (e. g. I can’t use `route` or `ifconfig`)... But I can’t get them with `apt-get` because `package net-tools has no installation candidate`, and I also can’t update `apt-get` because `some index files failed to download`.

Please help me. After reinstalling Linux 4 or 5 times I’m almost ready to give up.

EDIT: I’ve managed to use internet normally though mobile data hotspot, but still can’t use it normally with my router though and still looking for help.

EDIT2: `ifconfig` results:

```
enp0s20f0u1c4i2 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:f6:9c:6b:15:50  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:5b:76:f2:fb:43  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2869 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:2507747 (2.5 MB)  TX bytes:438042 (438.0 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3671 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:367117 (367.1 KB)  TX bytes:367117 (367.1 KB)

wlp2s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:3d:d4:94:cb:31  
          inet addr:172.20.10.2  Bcast:172.20.10.15  Mask:255.255.255.240
          inet6 addr: fe80::33a5:7e62:f8d3:2c40/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:68152 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:42710 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:82829898 (82.8 MB)  TX bytes:5837199 (5.8 MB)
```

`sudo lshw -c network` results:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: c8:5b:76:f2:fb:43
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: c8:3d:d4:94:cb:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.18.0-16-generic firmware=N/A ip=172.20.10.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b1003fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: enp0s20f0u1c4i2
       serial: 0a:f6:9c:6b:15:50
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ipheth link=no multicast=yes
```

EDIT3: `sudo lshw -c network` results using another Ethernet wall plate:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: enp1s0
       version: 10
       serial: c8:5b:76:f2:fb:43
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 00
       serial: c8:3d:d4:94:cb:31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8821ae driverversion=4.18.0-16-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:129 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b1003fff
```

EDIT4: providing more data:
[IPv4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueXkX.png)
[Missing DNS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsPif.png)

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr c8:5b:76:f2:fb:43  
          inet6 addr: 2a02:a31a:a13e:8100:680a:a096:883:85b2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::6a8c:a59f:47c3:4849/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: 2a02:a31a:a13e:8100:5046:dc7d:de0:1b96/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1400  Metric:1
          RX packets:2322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1955726 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:280257 (280.2 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:756 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:67313 (67.3 KB)  TX bytes:67313 (67.3 KB)
```

EDIT5: providing network card data: [drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3Z3a.png)

SOLUTION: resetting router/modem with directly unplugging it from elecricity, moving cables and rebooting Linux, hope it helps someone else with such a problem.

Comment: You can connect only IPv6 sites. So something is wrong with your IPv4.

Comment: please tell about the network setup (WiFi or Lan, Type of internet connection...)

Comment: I’ve tried both Wifi and LAN, both with same results. Both have the same WPA security.

Comment: Are you using a DSL connection? If so, what is your MTU set to in your computer, and in your router. Also, edit your question with the output of `ifconfig` and `sudo lshw -C network`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I think I'm using DSL... MTU should be visible in ifconfig results, which are in edited post.

Comment: This sounds like a network issue. Can other devices on your home network connect to the internet?

Comment: @wjandrea yes, they can, but they all use Windows. Windows 10 on my laptop (dual-boot with Ubuntu) also can use internet normally. I also didn't know how to tag people, I'm a newbie here (and Unix in general).

Comment: Please try to disable ipv6 in NetworkManager - See how from CLI : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wjQ664XjyS/

Comment: @cmak.fr I did it, after last command I get „Error: Connection activation failed: IP configuration could not be reserved (no available address, timeout, etc.)”

Comment: Before I make any recommendation, I need to know for sure if it's DSL or not... as we may need to change your MTU. Also, you probably have a cable issue, as you're only getting a 10Mb half-duplex connection. Please explain EXACTLY how your network is wired, from the computer port to the cable/dsl modem. Be prepared to swap an ethernet cable shortly. Start comments to me with @heynnema

Comment: @cmak.fr why wouldn't you instruct OP to use the NM GUI to disable IPv6?

Comment: @heynnema I’ve tried disabling IPv6 through NM, it didn’t work (that was one of the solutions from other threads). My flat gets Ethernet cable from ISP, which is connected to router, from which go 2 Ethernet cables to separate rooms (inside walls), and there is a socket at the end in which I plug Ethernet-Eternet cable.

Comment: OK, then do EITHER one of these... replace the ethernet cable from your computer to the wall plate... OR plug your existing ethernet cable into the OTHER wall plate... and monitor `sudo lshw -c network` and watch if you get better than a 10Mb half-duplex connection on enp1s0. Also... do you have a USB ethernet adapter plugged in?

Comment: @neynnema I edited my post with the results. And no, I don't use USB adapter, only Ethernet-Ethernet plug or Ethernet-Ethernet cable.

Comment: You fixed it. If you used the same ethernet-ethernet cable, then your original wall plate cable/connection is defective. Please see my answer. Please remember to accept it if it was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments...

Using `sudo lshw -C network` we see...

We started with enp1s0 showing "**duplex=half** firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 **link=no** multicast=yes port=MII **speed=10Mbit/s**".

After reconnecting to a different ethernet wall plate, emp1s0 now shows "**duplex=full** firmware=rtl8168g-3_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 **link=yes** multicast=yes port=MII **speed=1Gbit/s**".

You fixed it. Internet should be working now.

You have either a bad external ethernet-ethernet cable, or a bad ethernet cable in the wall connecting to the router. Replace it.

**Update #1:**

Well... it's not fixed. We have more than one problem. It appears that we might have a bad ethernet wall plate/internal ethernet wire problem. Wall plate #1 doesn't work. Wall plate #2 works.

We found that the "Wired Connection" profile had MTU=1400. Totally wrong for a cable modem environment. We changed it to AUTO/1500.

**Update #2:**

We're going to temporarily try a manual connection. Maybe it'll give us more clues.

```
address=192.168.0.100 (I'm picking this address out of the air).
netmask=24
gateway=192.168.0.1
dns=8.8.8.8
```

See if Internet and ping work now. You should be able to ping 192.168.0.1 and 8.8.8.8.

**Update #3:**

Even with a manual "Wired Connection" profile, it still didn't work!

We're going to try using this laptop at another site and see if it works there.

**Update #4:**

After not working with Ubuntu, Debian and Fedora, we found multiple problems, but a few more power cycles of the modem and laptop, and it's working now. It sounds like the modem/router needed to actually pull the power plug to properly reset it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90828/discussion-on-answer-by-heynnema-can-only-use-a-few-sites).

Comment: So this is the last comment: it finally worked! I tried rebooting router (not with buttons, but directly unplugging it from electricity) and laptop many times, changing cables, resetting to factory settings etc. and it all works now! With both Ethernet connection (on both wall plates) and wifi on automatic settings! I have absolutely no idea why it works now, but thank you very, very much for all your help.